# @Import vs @ContextConfiguration in SpringBoot application tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit

Just find out that `@Import` annotation could be used in unit test of spring boot application to load configurations which are needed for the test. My question is about how correct this approach is. Is there some possible problems or traps here?

For now I found only one difference in behaviour. I have an abstract parent class for all tests with an internal `@TestConfiguration` static class in it with some common beans for testing. If I use `@ContextConfiguration` I should explicitly list it in the classes option of this annotation but with `@Import` it will be loaded automatically without explicit import. That the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: `@Import` works by accident and shouldn't be used for this. With the recent changes in Spring 5.1 it might even stop working.

Comment: And could you guess about reasons of such accident?

Comment: It is the way auto wiring is is implemented in the specific `TestExecutionListener` with how `Configuration` classes or specifically non `@Configuration` classes where processed on additional annotations. The latter behavior changed in Spring 5.1. If you want that `@TestConfiguration` class (which is Spring Boot and not regular Spring) loaded add an `@ContextConfiguration` to that base class which loads that configuration class. All `@ContextConfiguration` annotations in the test class hierarchy are merged and everything is processed and loaded.

Comment: Now it's more clear. Thank you!